# Google sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script

i started to write google scripts a few weeks ago. i am not really familar with the syntax. Therefore i am asking you to give me support to complete my script.
I have a google sheet, that needs to be filled automatically by a bluettoth caliper. The caliper will send the measured value to the activated cell and jumps to the next cell below. There are 6 items be measured. Each measurement result have to be judged by the script. Is the measured value between the specified limits (in this case 'frontier_1 and frontier_2'). Depending on the result, the cell has to be colored red or green.
After the last measurement, a pop up window should be displayed with the hint that the measurement is completed.

I tried to colorize the cells with the trigger (onEdit()). But i have difficulties to judge the result and to stop the process after the last last item was measured.

Hope you can help me!

Thats the code for AppScript:

```
    function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Test_environment')
  .addItem('1__configure_sheet', 'configuration')
  .addItem('2__start_measurement','measurement')
  .addToUi();

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TEST').getRange('A1').setValue('Name');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TEST').getRange('B1').setValue('Frontier_1');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TEST').getRange('C1').setValue('Frontier_2');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TEST').getRange('D1').setValue('Measured_value');

}

function configuration()  {
  var ui  = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt('Enter -Test-');
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    ui.alert('You have entered -Test-. Loading appropriate dataset...');
  }
  else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL)  {
    ui.alert('Please enter -Test-');
  }
  else if ( button == ui.Button.CLOSE)  {
    ui.alert('The application will be closed');
  }
  if (text == 'Test') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TEST').getRange('A2:A7').setValues([['Item_1'],['Item_2'],['Item_3'],['Item_4'],['Item_5'],['Item_6']]);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TEST').getRange('B2:C7').setValues([[2,2],[2,2],[2,2],[2,2],[2,2],[2,2]]);
    debugger
  }
  else if (text != 'Test')  {
    ui.alert('Wrong name. Please enter -Test-');
  }
}

function measurement() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TEST').getRange('D2').activate();
}

function onEdit(e)  {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const firstRow = 2 // Column D in active sheet;

  for (var row=2; row <= lastRow; row++)  {
    // Step 1 = check if value is less than 'Frontier_1 && larger than 'Frontier_2
    // if yes = colorize cell 'green'
    // if not = colorize cell 'red'

    // loop runs until last Row (Name). Then show a prompt and deactivate cell.

  }
}
```

Comment: How does your bluetooth caliper send data to Google Sheets? onEdit(e) will only respond to user input.

Answer (score 0):

The caliper send the the value via Bluetooth. You have activate a Cell at first. Then you have to push a Button on the caliper and the value is being send to the cell.